# validação no IF JQuery

Tags: jquery

boa tarde,

tenho varias telas que fica escondida(fade), quando clicado em um botão ela aparece.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#animate").click(function() {
            $('#content').animate({"left": "100%"}, 1500);
            $('#content2').animate({"right": "100%"},1500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Tenho essas ID: animate, animateServico, animatePortifolio.

eu queria saber como fazer uma validação, para que, quando clicar em algum botão que tenha umas das ID ela faça os comandos.

exemplo: quando clicado no animate, quero que a tela ande X px, se clicado no animateServico a tela ande X px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer adicionar o *EventListener* simultaneamente nos elementos que possuem os IDs: `animate`, `animateServico`, `animatePortifolio`.

Você pode fazer isso, simplesmente adicionando os outros IDs com uma vírgula ao *selector*, dessa forma:

```
$("#animate, #animateServico, #animatePortifolio").click(function() {
    //ação que você deseja
});
```

**[Editado]**

Diante do que você falou nos comentários, já contrariando minha própria afirmação, você pode usar a abordagem acima, manipulando com o próprio `if`, qual tela você deseja abrir.

Existem duas formas de abrir uma tela específica, de acordo com o elemento que foi clicado:

**Forma 1**

Você pode obter o `id` do elemento clicado, e assim, você elabora um bloco `if`, dessa forma:

```
$("#animate, #animateServico, #animatePortifolio").click(function(event) { 
    //o "event" se faz necessário para obter-se o elemento clicado
    let targetId = event.target.id;
    if (targetId == "animate") {
        //ação 1
    } else if (targetId == "animateServico") {
        //ação 2
    } else if (targetId == "animatePortifolio") {
        //ação 3
    }
});
```

**Forma 2**

Você pode definir um *[data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)*, para logo depois obter o seu valor, e de acordo com o mesmo, abrir a tela desejada:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#animate, #animateServico, #animatePortifolio").click(function(event) { 
            $('#content').animate({"left": "100%"}, 1500); 
            $('#' + $(event.target).attr("data-tela")).animate({"right": "100%"},1500); 
         }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: mais desse jeito eu não teria o controle, pois todas as telas faria a mesma coisa ao mesmo tempo, para intender melhor, e o seguinte, tenho a tela principal com quatro opções, dependendo a opção que escolho a principal some e abre a tela que foi escolhida.

Comment: Então, nesse caso, você teria que usar o *selector* de forma específica para cada um, ou seja, você teria que usar o *selector* três vezes para abrir as janelas específicas de cada botão.

Comment: achei que teia um mode de simplificar isso com o if, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu editei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Como o Gustavo colocou na resposta, use o `.target` para saber qual botão que disparou o evento:

```js
$("#animate, #animateServico, #animatePortifolio").click(function(e){
   
   var id = e.target.id; // pega o id do botão
   
   if(id == "animate"){
      
      console.log("botão animate");
      
   }else if(id == "animateServico"){

      console.log("botão animateServiço");

   }else{

      console.log("botão animatePortifolio");

   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="animate">animate</button>
<button id="animateServico">animateServico</button>
<button id="animatePortifolio">animatePortifolio</button>
```